# Sulu CMS: how to search/filter for content of a specific type with specific values for specifc attributes?

Tags: sulu

Short description of the situation:

- We're running a forked version of Sulu 1.5.2, PHP 7.1, Windows server environment, db connection with PostgreSQL
- We have a website structure/tree where we have `house` templates at the top level; each house has one `house_rooms` and one `house_occupants` template; each `house_rooms` template has N `house_rooms_room` templates, and each `house_occupants` template has N `house_occupants_occupant` templates. This represents an actual House that has N Rooms and N Occupants.

Now I'd like to know if there is a way to specifically get, for instance, *all* the `house_occupants_occupant` content that follows a certain pattern of attributes (for instance: their `gender` attribute having value 'female' and their `date_of_birth` parameter being >= 1990/01/01), without having to load each `house`, then find its `house_occupants`page among the children, and then loop over that template's `house_occupants_occupant` children and filter the thus begotten content according to their gender and date of birth attributes.

I already found that there is a [ContentRepository](http://docs.sulu.io/en/latest/bundles/content/content-repository.html) class that can `::findAll()` and `::findByUuids()`, but there doesn't seem to be a way to filter on specific attributes (like template type, template attributes, ...). So I took a roundabout way of creating my own "repository" that does direct PDO queries on the `phpcr_nodes` table in the database, to specifically scan the `props` attribute for the occurence of a certain template name:

```
$this->pdo->query("SELECT identifier, props FROM phpcr_nodes WHERE props LIKE '%>house_occupants_occupant<%'");
```

I can see that the `props`contains a string value representing an XML document that somehow translates into the entire template with attribute-value pairs, however it is obscured regarding tag-levels and how certain attributes relate to certain values. So *in theory* I could use a specific XML parser to turn this into something human-readable, so that for my `house_occupants_occupant` data I could get something like:

```
// what I would get after putting the props through a certain XML parser:
$xmlHumanReadableData = [
    '<the_uuid_of_occupant_1>' => [
        ...
        'gender' => 'female',
        'date_of_birth' => '1992-05-18T00:00:00.000+00:00',
        ...
    ],
    ... //etcetera etcetera
];
```

When I would have that, I could filter the readable data to ascertain which content I want to keep, add the node-uuid to some `$theUuids` variable, and then retrieve the actual content using Sulu's `ContentRepository::findByUuids($theUuids)` method. That would "only" require 2 queries and some PHP array filtering in between, which is a great deal better than looping over all the children content starting from a certain parent and doing this until you've traversed all the parents and all their children... (Certainly, the overhead would increase if you'd want to search for, for instance, all `house` nodes where at least one of its `house_occupants_occupant` nodes represents a child less than 10 years old, since you'd need extra queries to "set up" the filterdata used in the final query. But still: a great deal better than looping everything... ;-) )

So my question is sort-of twofold:

- What is the Sulu-specific XML parser I can use to turn the XML string value in this `props` column into something human-readable, with proper attribute-value pairs?
- And/or, hopefully: is there a way I can avoid all this nonsense and just use a less low-level way of retrieving content of a *specific template type* with *specific values* for *specific attributes* ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ContentRepository` you've found is already an abstraction to some of our requirements for pages. Your requirements are already quite specific, so you should write your own query using SQL-2, the [query language for PHPCR](http://phpcr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/book/query.html).

This should enable you to write a query which matches your requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll read up on that and get back to this post once I gave that a shot :)